Why doesn't rapier3d collision detection work in bevy engine?
I am developing a game using bevy 0.14. I am slowly progressing through the manual. I tried to detect collisions using rapier3d.
Since there is no response, I want to check if the settings are incorrect.
I checked the manual several times and proceeded with coding, but no crash events were detected, so I want to know what the problem is with my code.
The code below is my code so far. Why doesn't the crash event occur here?
use bevy::input::mouse::{MouseMotion, MouseWheel};
use bevy::prelude::*;
use bevy_rapier3d::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    App::new().
        add_plugins(DefaultPlugins).
        add_plugins(RapierPhysicsPlugin::<NoUserData>::default()).
        add_plugins(RapierDebugRenderPlugin::default()).
        add_systems(Startup, init_object).
        add_systems(Update, (player_movement, camera_movement)).
        add_systems(PostUpdate, landed_player_check).
        run();
}

// 플레이어 컴포넌트 정의
#[derive(Component)]
struct Player {
    is_jumping: bool,
}

impl Default for Player {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {is_jumping: false}
    }
}

#[derive(Component)]
struct Camera;

#[derive(Component)]
struct CameraFollow {
    offset: Vec3,    
}

#[derive(Component)]
struct Ground;


fn init_object(
    mut commands: Commands,
    mut meshes: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
    mut materials: ResMut<Assets<StandardMaterial>>,
) {
    // 바닥
    commands.spawn((
        PbrBundle {
            mesh: meshes.add(Plane3d::default().mesh().size(20., 20.)),
            material: materials.add(Color::srgb_u8(255, 0, 0)),
            transform: Transform::from_xyz(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
            ..default()
        },
        Collider::cuboid(10.0, 0.0, 10.0), 
        Ground,
    ));


    // 플레이어
    commands.spawn((
        PbrBundle {
            mesh: meshes.add(Cuboid::new(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
            transform: Transform::from_xyz(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), 킴
            material: materials.add(StandardMaterial {
                base_color: Color::WHITE,
                ..default()
            }),
            ..default()
        },
        Player::default(),
        RigidBody::Dynamic,
        Collider::cuboid(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), 
        GravityScale(10.0),
    ));

    // 빛
    commands.spawn(DirectionalLightBundle {
        transform: Transform::from_translation(Vec3::ONE).looking_at(Vec3::ZERO, Vec3::Y),
        ..default()
    });


    // 카메라
    commands.spawn((
        Camera3dBundle {
            transform: Transform::from_xyz(0.0, 10.0, 10.0).looking_at(Vec3::ZERO, Vec3::Y),
            ..default()
        },
        Camera,
        CameraFollow {
            offset: Vec3::new(0.0, 10.0, 10.0), 
        },
    ));
}


fn player_movement(
    mut query: Query<(&mut Transform, &mut Player), With<Player>>, 
    keyboard_input: Res<ButtonInput<KeyCode>>,
    time: Res<Time>, 
) {
    let speed = 10.0;

    // 쿼리된 엔티티들의 Transform 반복 처리
    if let Ok((mut transform, mut player_state)) = query.get_single_mut() {
        if !player_state.is_jumping {
            let mut direction = Vec3::ZERO;
            if keyboard_input.pressed(KeyCode::KeyW) {
                direction.z -= 1.0;
            }
            if keyboard_input.pressed(KeyCode::KeyS) {
                direction.z += 1.0;
            }
            if keyboard_input.pressed(KeyCode::KeyA) {
                direction.x -= 1.0;
            }
            if keyboard_input.pressed(KeyCode::KeyD) {
                direction.x += 1.0;
            }
            if keyboard_input.pressed(KeyCode::Space) {
                player_state.is_jumping = true;
                direction.y += 10.0;
            }
            transform.translation += direction * speed * time.delta_seconds();
        }
    }
}


fn camera_movement(
    mut param_set: ParamSet<(
        Query<(&mut Transform, &mut Player), With<Player>>,  // 플레이어 쿼리
        Query<(&mut Transform, &mut CameraFollow), With<Camera>>,  // 카메라 쿼리
    )>,
    mouse_button: Res<ButtonInput<MouseButton>>,
    mut mouse_motion: EventReader<MouseMotion>,
    mut wheel_event: EventReader<MouseWheel>,
) {
    let zoom_speed = 0.5;



    // 마우스 중앙 버튼을 누른 경우, 카메라 회전을 처리합니다.
    if mouse_button.pressed(MouseButton::Middle) {
        for mouse_move_event in mouse_motion.read() {
            if let Ok((player_transform, _)) = param_set.p0().get_single() {
                let player_position = player_transform.translation;  // 플레이어 위치를 먼저 가져옴

                if let Ok((mut camera_transform, mut camera_follow)) = param_set.p1().get_single_mut() {
                    // 좌우 회전은 월드 Y축, 상하 회전은 카메라 로컬 X축을 기준으로 처리
                    // 음수를 곱해 마우스 이동 방향을 반전시킴
                    let rotation = Quat::from_rotation_y(-mouse_move_event.delta.x * 0.005)
                        * Quat::from_axis_angle(*camera_transform.local_x(), -mouse_move_event.delta.y * 0.005);

                    // 카메라 오프셋을 회전시켜 새로운 위치 계산
                    camera_follow.offset = rotation * camera_follow.offset;
                    camera_transform.translation = player_position + camera_follow.offset;

                    // 카메라가 항상 플레이어를 바라보도록 설정
                    camera_transform.look_at(player_position, Vec3::Y);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    // 이제 카메라의 위치를 수정합니다.
    if let Ok((player_transform, _)) = param_set.p0().get_single() {
        let player_position = player_transform.translation;
        if let Ok((mut camera_transform, camera_follow)) = param_set.p1().get_single_mut() {
            camera_transform.translation = player_position + camera_follow.offset;
            camera_transform.look_at(player_position, Vec3::Y);
        }
    }


    // 휠로 줌을 조정할 때, 오프셋을 Z축 방향으로만 조정합니다.
    for v in wheel_event.read() {
        if let Ok((_, mut camera_follow)) = param_set.p1().get_single_mut() {
            // Z축 오프셋만 조정하여 줌을 적용
            let zoom_delta = -v.y * zoom_speed;
            let offset_length = camera_follow.offset.length();

            // 줌 범위를 제한하고 오프셋을 조정
            let new_length = (offset_length + zoom_delta).clamp(5.0, 20.0);
            camera_follow.offset = camera_follow.offset.normalize() * new_length;
        }
    }
}


fn landed_player_check(
    mut collision_events: EventReader<CollisionEvent>,
    player_query: Query<Entity, With<Player>>,
    ground_query: Query<Entity, With<Ground>>,
) {
    let player_entity = player_query.get_single().ok();
    let ground_entity = ground_query.get_single().ok();

    for event in collision_events.read() {
        println!("Collision event detected: {:?}", event);
        match event {
            CollisionEvent::Started(entity1, entity2, _) => {
                println!("entity1: {:?}, entity2: {:?}", entity1, entity2);

                if let (Some(player), Some(ground)) = (player_entity, ground_entity) {
                    println!("Player Entity: {:?}, Ground Entity: {:?}", player, ground);

                    if (*entity1 == player && *entity2 == ground) || (*entity1 == ground && *entity2 == player) {
                        println!("플레이어가 바닥에 닿았습니다.");
                    } else {
                        println!("충돌은 발생했지만 플레이어와 바닥이 아닙니다.");
                    }
                }
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}


I recently struggled with this as well. According to the official documentation, you have to explicitly enable collisions between specific types of rigid bodies and colliders.
The documentation of ActiveCollisionTypes has some detailed description of what is supported, but I think in your case, you'll have to enable the DYNAMIC_STATIC collision types, since your simulated entities are a mixture of dynamic (RigidBody::Dynamic) and static (no RigidBody component at all).
 commands.spawn((
    PbrBundle {
        mesh: meshes.add(Cuboid::new(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), 킴
        material: materials.add(StandardMaterial {
            base_color: Color::WHITE,
            ..default()
        }),
        ..default()
    },
    Player::default(),
    RigidBody::Dynamic,
    Collider::cuboid(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), 

    ActiveCollisionTypes::DYNAMIC_STATIC,
    // Add the above component.
    //
    // Alternatively, you can add `ActiveCollisionTypes::default()`,
    // which includes the `DYNAMIC_STATIC` flag.

    GravityScale(10.0),
));


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
